# Pass button text/name as parameter to a sub/function

Tags: excel, vba

I have 4 buttons - as shapes, because I want to apply some style to them - that all have different text in them and are named differently, otherwise they are the same.

I want to assign same sub to all of them that would accept the button text or name as argument and perform slightly different operation based on what text/name was passed to the sub.

Is it possible? Or do I have to create 4 subs, each for 1 button?

Code draft:

```
Sub button_pressed(button_text as string)

If button_text = "A" then
    do something
Else if button text = "B" then
    do something else
'etc...
end if

End sub
```

Comment: Yes it is possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If they are shapes, just assign the same macro to all of them and test `Application.Caller` in the macro:

```
Sub button_pressed()
dim button_text as string
button_text = application.caller
If button_text = "A" then
    do something
Elseif button_text = "B" then
    do something else
'etc...
end if

End sub
```

Although you can run into issues if the shape name is longer than 31 characters as `Application.Caller` only returns the first 31.

Comment: You beat me to it :-)

Answer (score 2):

If these are shapes with a macro assigned to them you can use Application.Caller to get the name of the clicked button. So:

```
Sub AssignedMacro()
    Select Case Application.Caller
    Case "ButtonCaption 1"
    Case "ButtonCaption 2"
    Case Else
    End Select
End Sub
```